# 3840x2160@60hz recognized during install, but not after install complete on 14.04.2

Tags: system-installation, xorg, resolution

I have a GTX670 graphics card and a Philips BDM4065UC monitor which is configured for displayport 1.2.

When I run Ubuntu 14.04.2 (amd64) from a USB boot mode using the tryme mode, my screen comes up as 3840x2160@60hz, so I know the card/monitor/driver configuration works.

When I run the install everything is fine, but after I reboot I only get 3840x2160@30hz.  I've tried using xrand, and as far as the system is concerned, 60hz is not supported.

To fix this, I figured the easiest way would be to copy the appropriate config files from the tryme setup into my permanent setup (I can easily reproduce this by booting from USB).

*Has someone come across this before, and can tell me how to fix my configuration to get 60hz?*

here is my monitors.xml file

no
      
      
      
          VSC
          0xf62b
          0x01010101
          1920
          1080
          60
          0
          0
          normal
          no
          no
          yes
      
      
      
      
          PHL
          0x08e1
          0x000016ec
          3840
          2160
          60
          1920
          0
          normal
          no
          no
          no

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu ;-) Could you [edit] your question and add the following information: nVidia module version and the contents of your `monitor.xml`.  If you don't know how to do this, please leave a comment below!  :-)

Comment: Please also post the requested information if you want to get to the bottom of this, because your solution is just a workaround... (staying away from nvidia drivers)  ;-)  :P

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to find the nVidia module version, and the formatting of the monitors.xml file doesn't display properly

Comment: `nvidia-settings --version` and post `monitors.xml` to http://paste.ubuntu.com and provide the link back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried several re-installs since posting the original question and I have been able to get my system running with 3840x2160@60hz.  This post is to help others who might have the same problem.

One of the things that concerned me about my setup is that I can't make the displayport output the primary monitor on the system if the DVI ports are used.  The GTX670 had 1xDP, 1xHDMI and 2xDVI ports.
I disconnected all other monitors except the BDM4065UC and reinstalled as normal (I have a dual-boot with win7, so I run boot-repair to fix grub after install).  This worked without a problem.
I then ran "sudo apt-get install nvidia-current" which caused me to lose my 60hz config, and I when back to only 30hz being supported.
I then tried re-installing again, this time with my other monitor connected (a Viewsonic 27", which runs 1920x1080@60hz).  The Viewsonic became the primary monitor, but the install still worked, and the BDM4065UC is running at 3840x2160@60hz.
I haven't been able to work out why the install didn't work previously, but I am keeping away from the nvidia driver at the moment.  I expect it doesn't support my monitor.
thanks to those who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` 
As that will install nvidia drivers.